# How to return an new Object as Value ?[Sequence Diagram]

Tags: software, sequence-diagram, sequence

within the sequence diagram it is possible to return a value, with return of a method edge, however this is usually done with a simple numeric or string value. Is it possible to return a whole object? For example, I have the task to create a coffee and put 3 sugars in it.

Classes: initiator-Customer, Coffee and Sugar.

Two scenarios for completion:

*First*

1. Customer calls new Coffee() which, generates a new coffee object
2. From coffe object, call the add sugar from Sugar class, three times(loop) with addSugar(this).
3. Return coffee object with 3 sugars to the Customer

*Second*

1. Customer calls new Coffee() which, generates a new coffee object
2. Return coffee object to customer class.
3. Call three times(loop) from customer the Sugar class with coffee object as parmeter.

Which one is better ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: You have a problem scenario and are asking which implementation is better.  However, there's no surrounding context to judge "better", and you also offer no criteria for what "better" means.  Better is usually in the context of usage scenarios.  If one or the other of these modeling abstractions work for your programming then great.  If you find one cumbersome for some reason, then change it; software is soft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Third*

1. Customer calls `new Coffee()` which generates a new coffee object
2. Return coffee object to customer class.
3. From Customer loop three times

   1. call the `new Sugar()` which generates a new sugar object
   2. Return sugar object to customer class.
   3. call the `addSugar()` method on the coffee object, passing the sugar object as parameter.